Using JQuery to alter text inputs on select change and document finish loading
Background: I have 3 forms on my page each with inputs that have the same class names. I have 2 scenarios:

When a user selects a specific option from the dropdown I want to
make the two text inputs below that specific select input not
editable and assign them values.

When the page loads or reloads I want to check all selects inputs
and if they have selected a specific option make the two text inputs
below not editable and assign them values.


I have scenario 1 working but I am disabling the text inputs so they are not posting when the form is submitted. I also feeling like there is a more eligant way of accomplishing my goal.
$('.icon_select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings('.icon_example').attr('src', 'https://weburl/images/writers/' + $(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() == 'share.png' || $(this).val() == 'not_active.png') {
        $(this).parent().siblings('p').children('.form-control').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).parent().siblings('p').children('.form-control').attr('value', 'N/A');          
    } else if ($(this).val() != 'share.png' && $(this).parent().siblings('p').children('.form-control').attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
        $(this).parent().siblings('p').children('.form-control').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).parent().siblings('p').children('.form-control').attr('value', $(this).val());
    }
    
});

Example of HTML with the option selected that changes the text inputs below it:
<img class="icon_example" src="https://newsite.inktip.com/images/writers/share.png" alt="Pitch">
    <h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-1">Select Icon:</h5>
        <p class="card-text">   
            <select name="icon_select[]" class="icon_select">
                <option value="not_active.png">-Not Active-</option>
                <option value="my_library.png">My Library</option>
                <option value="pitch.png">Pitch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="share.png">Share</option>
                <option value="share_tracker.png">Share Tracker</option>
                <option value="upgrade_pro.png">Upgrade Pro</option>
                <option value="upload_script.png">Upload Script</option>
                <option value="viewings.png">Viewings</option>
            </select>
        </p> 

        <h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-1">Link Title:</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm link-title" name="link_title[]" value="N/A" placeholder="Link Text" disabled="disabled"></p>
        <h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-1">Link URL:</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm link-url" name="link_url[]" value="N/A" placeholder="Link 1 URL" disabled="disabled"></p>

What I think would work best but not sure the best way to accomplish
use the .on() event that listens for the select inputs to change and for the page to complete loading. Either action fires off a function with a modified version of what I have above. The main difference if its page finished loading I would have to check all of the selects on the page.

You can use https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ to trigger an event - so inside a load/ready handler, you can simply trigger the change handler you already assigned to these select fields, to get this done on page load.

Why not move the code into a Function of it's own and execute on change and load?

Consider the following example.


$(function() {
  $('.icon_select').change(function() {
    console.log("Icon Select Change. Value: " + $(this).val());
    $self = $(this), $parent = $self.parent();
    $('.icon_example', $parent).attr('src', 'https://weburl/images/writers/' + $self.val());
    if ($self.val() == 'share.png' || $self.val() == 'not_active.png') {
      console.log("Selecting: " + $self.val() + ", Locking entries.");
      $('.form-control', $parent).prop('disabled', true).attr('value', 'N/A');
    } else if ($self.val() != 'share.png' && $parent.siblings('p').children('.form-control').prop('disabled')) {
      console.log("Unlocking entries");
      $('.form-control', $parent).prop('disabled', false).attr('value', $self.val());
    }
  });

  console.log("Icon Select Ready.");
  $('.icon_select').trigger("change");
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img class="icon_example" src="https://newsite.inktip.com/images/writers/share.png" alt="Pitch">
  <h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-1">Select Icon:</h5>
  <p class="card-text">
    <select name="icon_select[]" class="icon_select">
      <option value="not_active.png">-Not Active-</option>
      <option value="my_library.png">My Library</option>
      <option value="pitch.png">Pitch</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="share.png">Share</option>
      <option value="share_tracker.png">Share Tracker</option>
      <option value="upgrade_pro.png">Upgrade Pro</option>
      <option value="upload_script.png">Upload Script</option>
      <option value="viewings.png">Viewings</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-1">Link Title:</h5>
  <p class="card-text"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm link-title" name="link_title[]" value="N/A" placeholder="Link Text" disabled="disabled"></p>
  <h5 class="card-title mt-1 mb-1">Link URL:</h5>
  <p class="card-text"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm link-url" name="link_url[]" value="N/A" placeholder="Link 1 URL" disabled="disabled"></p>
</div>



With this code, the change event is trigger once the page is loaded. You may also notice a number of other code changes. These are largely just minor changes to make the code more efficient.
One thing that you do want to address in your code is surrounding disabled property. This is not an attribute of an element but a property. It is best to use .prop() to set this property to true or false as needed.
